# URL Param rewrite in node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Whenever a tag is submitted with spaces, the spaces show up as %20 in the response. How would I rewrite each space so in either the request and response it can be a dash? Are there any reliable library's for this? Thanks!

Route

```
 router.get('/search/:tag', function(req, res) {
      const tag = req.params.tag;
      tag.toLowerCase();
      shopify.article.list(86289414)
      .then(function (response) {
        response.reverse();

        response = response.map(function(element) {
            return {
              author: element.author,
              blog_id: element.blog_id,
              body_html: element.body_html,
              created_at: element.created_at,
              handle: element.handle,
              id: element.id,
              image: element.image,
              published_at: element.published_at,
              summary_html: element.summary_html,
              tags: element.tags.toString().toLowerCase(),
              template_suffix: element.template_suffix,
              title: element.title,
              updated_at: element.updated_at,
              user_id: element.user_id
            }
        })


        response = response.filter(function(item) {
         return item.tags.indexOf(tag) > -1;
       });

        var data = {
          articles: response.map((article) => {
            return {
              author: article.author,
              id: article.id,
              html: article.body_html,
              tags: article.tags.split(","),
              date: moment(article.published_at).format("Do MMM YYYY"),
              slug: article.handle,
              title: article.title,
            } // return
          }) // map
        } // data

          console.log(data);
          res.render('blog-tags' , data);

      }) // then
        .catch(err => console.log(err) )
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this will not do what you expect:

```
tag.toLowerCase();
```

You need to use:

```
tag = tag.toLowerCase();
```

if you want the value in the `tag` variable to change.

That is because strings in JavaScript are immutable and no operation can change a string, you can only replace the values of variables with new strings. And methods like `.toLowerCase()` always return a new string.

Now, if your variable already contains '%20' etc. then you need to use:

```
tag = decodeURIComponent(tag);
```

but note that this is likely to already be handled by the framework.

Now, to change spaces to underscores, use:

```
tag = tag.replace(/ /g, '_');
```

You can combine all of that as:

```
tag = decodeURIComponent(tag).toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_');
```

Or this if your variable already contains decoded string:

```
tag = tag.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_');
```

Example:

```
let tag = 'Aaa%20BbB%20cCC';
tag = decodeURIComponent(tag).toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_');
console.log(tag);
// prints: aaa_bbb_ccc
```

Comment: To be honest, I'm unsure where the %20 comes into play. When the url /blog/Leak Sensor is clicked will return /blog/Leak%20Sensor in the browser. And I edited my post, I realize I need it to work both ways.

Comment: @Quesofat URLs cannot contain a real space because it would break the HTTP protocol so the server will always get the space as %20 or as + (a plus) depending on where it is. So all spaces will always be posted encoded if they are in the URL.

Comment: Ok. The only thing is when I log the tag after the route's initiation it logs with a space. Will this solution still work even though it is a space? It doesn't seem like it because it assumes that the %20.

Comment: @Quesofat The `decodeURIComponent()` function doesn't change real spaces so if the string contains %20 it will be changed to a space but if it has a real space already then the space will still be there after that. In other words this: `decodeURIComponent('the%20tag') === decodeURIComponent('the tag')` (the second string has a real space) returns `true` so spaces don't have to be in the form of %20 for that code to work.